# angular - this declaration field is always false even though the checkbox checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

The below code always `returns false` even after I click the `checkbox`. My lead advised me that the `ngmodel` might not be hookedup properly with the state. I am new to angular, could someone pls help me

HTML:

```
<form-checkbox 
                required="true" 
                set-checkbox-touched="DeclarationRequest.declarationAgree"  
                servervalidate="DeclarationRequest.declarationAgree"
                name="declarationAgree"  id="declarationAgree" class="form-checkbox" ng-model="ctrl.checkbox.myFlag">I have read and agree to the terms above.</form-checkbox>
```

JS:

```
(function(module){
'use strict';
  module.directive('Declaration', function () {
      return {
        templateUrl: '/client/Purchase/components/declaration/declaration.template.html',
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            declarationAgree: '='
        },
        bindToController: true,
        controllerAs: 'control',
        controller: 'DeclarationController'
      };
  });

  function DeclarationController() {

  }

  module.controller('DeclarationController', DeclarationController );
    DeclarationController.$inject = [];

})(angular.module('Purchase'));
```

Comment: Can you put your $scope object in the question?

Comment: @Jai: Updated mate, but I don't think that's quite relevant here to give a solution or fix. But here you go, have a look and let me know what's wrong?

Comment: your code "always returns false" ...from where?

Answer (score -1):

You can put the ng-true-value or ng-false-value for your own false/true value , this code is from the guideline of angularjs.

```
<script>
  angular.module('checkboxExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.checkboxModel = {
       value1 : true,
       value2 : 'YES'
     };
    }]);
</script>
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <label>Value1:
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxModel.value1">
  </label><br/>
  <label>Value2:
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxModel.value2"
           ng-true-value="'YES'" ng-false-value="'NO'">
   </label><br/>
  <tt>value1 = {{checkboxModel.value1}}</tt><br/>
  <tt>value2 = {{checkboxModel.value2}}</tt><br/>
 </form>
```